# Launching an App automatically without clicking a button on xamarin forms on notifications

Tags: xamarin

I have a mobile application that displays 2 outcomes either a success or an error as a list view every few minutes from an API

I am using Xamarin Forms - cross platform shared project.

I wanted to know if there is a way to automatically open the app when it is running on the phone background whenever the app displays an error only.

Comment: You can never `force` your app to regain foreground consciousness when it was placed in the background by the user. IE: If the app is in the background, you cannot bring it to the foreground programatically. The user has to do that themselves.

Comment: Ahhh I see I see, Yep I got the concept. Thank You :)